# Fail when install Signr via Nuget in Visual Studio 2012: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values

Tags: .net, signalr, nuget, nuget-package

I'm attempting to install SignalR using:

```
    install-package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
```

I use Visual Studio 2012. Follwing that tutorial:[Getting Started with SignalR 2.0 and MVC 5](http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-getting-started-with-signalr-20-and-mvc-5)
  When I try install 'Signalr' and getting an error stating that `Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: supportedFrameworks`. Anyone have any idea why this would be? Below is the full output:

```
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS (≥ 2.0.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'jQuery (≥ 1.6.4)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb (≥ 2.0.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core (≥ 2.0.2)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Newtonsoft.Json (≥ 5.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Owin (≥ 1.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Owin (≥ 2.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Owin.Security (≥ 2.0.0)'.
Attempting to resolve dependency 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb (≥ 2.0.0)'.
Installing 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.1'.
Successfully installed 'Newtonsoft.Json 5.0.1'.
Installing 'Owin 1.0'.
Successfully installed 'Owin 1.0'.
Installing 'Microsoft.Owin 2.0.0'.
You are downloading Microsoft.Owin from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/aspnetcomponent_rtw_enu.htm. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Owin 2.0.0'.
Installing 'Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.0.0'.
You are downloading Microsoft.Owin.Security from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/aspnetcomponent_rtw_enu.htm. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.0.0'.
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 2.0.2'.
You are downloading Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/aspnetcomponent_rtw_ENU.htm. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core 2.0.2'.
Installing 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 2.0.0'.
You are downloading Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/aspnetcomponent_rtw_enu.htm. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb 2.0.0'.
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb 2.0.2'.
You are downloading Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/aspnetcomponent_rtw_ENU.htm. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.SystemWeb 2.0.2'.
Installing 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR 2.0.2'.
You are downloading Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR from Microsoft, the license agreement to which is available at http://www.microsoft.com/web/webpi/eula/aspnetcomponent_rtw_ENU.htm. Check the package for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their license agreements. If you do not accept the license agreement(s), then delete the relevant components from your device.
Successfully installed 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR 2.0.2'.
Adding 'jQuery 1.6.4' to SignalRChat2.
Successfully added 'jQuery 1.6.4' to SignalRChat2.
Adding 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS 2.0.2' to SignalRChat2.
Successfully added 'Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS 2.0.2' to SignalRChat2.
Removing 'Newtonsoft.Json 4.5.11' from SignalRChat2.
Install failed. Rolling back...
install-package : Specified argument was out of the range of valid values.
Parameter name: supportedFrameworks
At line:1 char:1
+ install-package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Install-Package], ArgumentOutOfRangeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : NuGetCmdletUnhandledException,NuGet.PowerShell.Commands.InstallPackageCommand
```

I tried with changing framework 4, 4.5, 4.5.1 for MVC 4, 5. All have the same issue

Comment: What .Net frame work are you targeting ?

Answer (score 0):

can you try install the latest NuGet from Tools->Extension and Updates to see if this still repro?

Comment: I use VS 2012 and try install both with VS 2013. And the problem was disappeard